# Local Tate duality for F-vector space

Tags: galois-representations, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology, pontrjagin-duality

A version of local Tate duality stated: Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, $A$ be a finite $G_K=Gal(\overline K/K)$ module. Then for $0\le i\le 2$, the cup product induces a perfect pairing $H^i(G_K,A)\times H^{2-i}(G_K,A')\to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, where $A'=Hom(A,\overline K^\times)$. In particular, there is a canonical isomorphism
$$H^i(G_K,A)\cong H^{2-i}(G_K,A')^\vee,$$ where $^\vee=Hom(\cdot,\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z).$

However, another version is used when studying the global/local deformation ring: Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, $\mathbb F$ be its residue field, and $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb F$-vector space with a continuous $G_K$ action. Let $V^*$ be the dual representation. Then for $0\le i\le 2$, there is a canonical isomorphism
$$H^i(G_K,V) \cong H^{2-i}(G_K,V^*(1))^*. $$

Can I ask whether it is possible to derive the second version from the first one? If not, is there a reference for the proof of the second version?

Comment: You have explained the notation $A'$  and $(\ )^\vee$, but not $V^*(1)$ and $(\ )^*$.  Please kindly explain!

Comment: Probably, when expalining, you will see yourself that (2) follows from (1)...

Comment: $()^*=Hom_{\mathbb F}(\cdot,\mathbb F)$ is the $\mathbb F$-linear dual and $V^*(1)=V^*\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p}\mathbb Z_p(1)$ means the Tate twist of $V^*$, where $\mathbb Z_p(1)$ is the p-adic cyclotomic character of $G_K$.

Comment: Does it help to note that if $\mathbb{L} / \mathbb{F}$ is an extension of finite fields, then the functors on $\mathbb{L}$-vector spaces given by $Hom_{\mathbb{L}}(-, \mathbb{L})$ and $Hom_{\mathbb{F}}(-, \mathbb{F})$ are canonically the same?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: Yes, it does help! But how do you define the isomorphism of your two functors, and why is it  indeed an isomorphism?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi The natural transformation $Hom_L(-, L) \to Hom_F(-, F)$ is composing with trace. The transformation $Hom_F(-, F) \to Hom_L(-, L)$ is the composite of base-extension $Hom_F(V, F) \to Hom_L(V \otimes_F L, L)$ with the embedding $V \into V \otimes_F L$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks a lot for your comment. Although I agree that the natural transformation $Hom_L(-, L) \to Hom_F(-, F)$ given by composing with trace is an isomorphism (by using that $Tr_{L/K}$ is non-trivial for finite separable $L/K$), I don't think the inverse is what you described. If I'm not mistaken, it just sends a $F$-linear map to itself.

Comment: @user14411 Not every F-linear functional on an L-vector space is L-linear, so "itself" is not going to be an element of Hom_L(-, L) in general.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I agree. The inverse is definitely not just sending a map to itself. What I meant was that in your previous comment, you said the transformation $Hom_F(-, F) \to Hom_L(-, L)$ was obtained by sending a map $V\to F$ to $V \to V\otimes_F L \to L$. But this actually just sends a map to itself, which is not the inverse.

Comment: No, that's not what it does. (Perhaps you are using the wrong inclusion $V \into V \otimes_F L$; I don't mean the one given by $v \mapsto v \otimes 1$.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I see. Sorry for misunderstanding your comment. May I ask which inclusion $V\to V\otimes_F L$ should I take?

Comment: $V \otimes_F L$ is canonically isomorphic to $V \oplus V$ and you take the inclusion of one summand (*not* the diagonal inclusion, which is what you are taking)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I'm afraid that I couldn't see why $V \otimes_F L$ is canonically isomorphic to $V\oplus V$. Would you mind explaining this please? Also, is the map $V\to V\otimes_F L$ canonical (independent of the choice of the summand that I embed $V$ into)? Sorry for asking these probably stupid questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146228/discussion-between-david-loeffler-and-user14411).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I treat the general case.
Write ${\Bbb F}={\Bbb F}_q$ where $q=p^l$ for some natural $l$.
Then ${{\Bbb F}}_q\supseteq {{\Bbb F}}_p={\Bbb Z}/p{\Bbb Z}$.

Using [a comment of @DavidLoeffler](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/445288/local-tate-duality-for-f-vector-space?noredirect=1#comment1152371_445288),
we obtain that
for an ${\Bbb F}$-vector space $W$, we can identify
\begin{multline*}
W^*={\rm Hom}_{{\Bbb F}}(W, {\Bbb F})\cong {\rm Hom}_{{{\Bbb F}_p}}(W, {\Bbb F}_p)
={\rm Hom}(W, {\Bbb Z}/p{\Bbb Z})\\
\cong{\rm Hom}(W, \tfrac1p{\Bbb Z}/{\Bbb Z})
={\rm Hom}(W, {\Bbb Q}/{\Bbb Z})=W^\vee.
\end{multline*}

By definition, our $V$ is a finite $G_K$-module and
$$ V^*(1)\cong{\rm Hom}_{{\Bbb F}}(V,{{\Bbb F}})\otimes_{{{{\Bbb F}_p}}}\mu_p$$
where $\mu_p$ denotes the group of roots of unity of degree dividing $p$ in $\overline K^\times$.
We can identify
\begin{multline*}
V^*(1)\cong{\rm Hom}_{{\Bbb F}}(V,{{\Bbb F}})\otimes_{{{{\Bbb F}_p}}}\mu_p\cong {\rm Hom}(V,{\Bbb Z}/p{\Bbb Z})\otimes_{{{\Bbb F}_p}} \mu_p\\
\cong {\rm Hom}(V,\mu_p)={\rm Hom}(V, \overline K^\times)=V'.
\end{multline*}

We conclude that
$$H^{2-i}(G_K,V^*(1))^*\cong H^{2-i}(G_K, V')^\vee. $$
Now we see that  the second assertion of the question is a special case of the first one.

Comment: I cannot treat the case of $q=p^l$ when $l>1$ because I don't understand your definition of $V^*(1)$. Try to unravle the definition and to construct a $G_K$-equivariant bilinear pairing $$V\times V^*(1) \to \mu_q. $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the definition of $V^*(1)$, we view $V^*=Hom_{\mathbb F}(V,\mathbb F)$ as a $\mathbb Z_p$-module by  letting $\mathbb Z_p$ acts on $\mathbb F$ via $\mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb F_p\to \mathbb F$. In case it helps, this statement of local Tate duality appears on p.32 of [link](https://users.math.yale.edu/~rz289/Galois_reps.pdf), though his notation is slightly different from mine.